# Three players with their own coin flip untill they have heads. The first one with heads wins

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution

I have been stuck with this question for some time and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

There are three players who each have their own coin—each coin having a different probability for it to land on heads. They play this game simultaneously, the first one to flip heads wins the game.

Let $X$ be the number of flips player 1 needs to get heads, $Y$ the number of flips for player 2 till he has heads,  and $Z$ be the flips for player 3 till he has heads.

Now I noted this down as $X\sim \textrm{Geom}(p), Y\sim \textrm{Geom}(q)$, and $Z\sim \textrm{Geom}(r)$. These three variables are independent.

My first question would be: What is the probability that player 1 wins? 
I thought it was enough to calculate $\mathrm{P}(X < Y < Z) + \mathrm{P}(X < Z < Y)$.

But now I'm not sure that this is enough.

I'm also not so sure about this: the number of turns needed to determine the winner of this game would be the $\mathrm{Min}\{X, Y, Z\}$, since the first person to flip heads will win. Hence meaning that its the minimum right?

So the number of turns **after** the winner is known until the last person to flip heads would be the $M = \mathrm{Max}\{X,Y,Z\}$, after someone wins the game you go and play until everyone has heads. This would mean the maximum of the flips? So since these three variables are geometric and independent this comes down to:
$$
\mathrm{P} (M>m) = \mathrm{P} (X>m;  Y>m; Z>m)= ((1-p)(1-q)(1-r)^m)
$$

This means that $M$ is also Geometric but then moved to zero.

So I hope someone can maybe tell me if I'm doing this correctly, or if I should calculate these things differently.

Comment: You need to specify in a little more detail what "They play this game simultaneously, the first one to flip heads wins the game" means - what if e.g. X and Y both get a heads on their first toss?

Comment: Since $X, Y$, and $Z$ are claimed to be geometric random variables with different parameters, they are **not iid** random variables if you are using the standard meaning of iid _independent and identically distributed._  Clearly they are _not_ identically distributed.  Also, as silverfish asks, you need to specify what it means to be the first to toss a head in case of ties.

Comment: Simply ignore ties.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork please allow the original poster to specify the intent of their question.

Comment: Dilip: Yeah sorry about the iid, its clearly doesnt have the same parameter, its just independent. @Silverfish: Now to calculate that player 1 wins this game: You cant have two players that toss heads at the same time. So to calculate the player 1 wins:  if we think about this in turns we can say that player 1 wins in the kth turn. You have to assume that he can only win if no one else flipped heads before this kth turn and that in this turn no one else has heads. This is how I understand this, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Oh and @Glen_b I hope this explains it a bit more.

Comment: "You cant have two players that toss heads at the same time" - why is this true, if "They play this game simultaneously"? Do you mean that player 1 tosses first, then player 2, then player 3?

Comment: @Silverfish, this is an old exam question. To me it seems that in order for player 1 to win it means that no one else can toss heads before he does and that in the turn he does toss heads no one else does that. Maybe im just thinking about this the wrong way, but yeah do you have any suggestions? If two players do toss heads at the same time how can I calculate the probability that player 1 wins? It is in discrete time so tossing at the same time shouldnt be such a problem I think.

Comment: A straightforward (not very pretty) way to such problems is writing $p^{(k)}$ for the probability that player 1 wins *in turn k*. Then P(player 1 wins) is given by the sum of the series $p^{(1)}+p^{(2)}+p^{(3)}+...$ which is an easily summable geometric series. You need to get $p^{(1)}$ right (if players toss in sequence with player 1 going first then it's simply $p$, if they toss simultaneously it's harder: you also need to make sure players 2 and 3 don't get a head that turn). For $p^{(2)}$, find the probability the game even reaches a 2nd turn, aside from that it's much like $p^{(1)}$.

Comment: @Silverfish thats why I thought that calculating  $\mathrm{P}(X < Y < Z) + \mathrm{P}(X < Z < Y)$ would give me the result that I'm looking for. I think that that means that player one needs less turns to toss heads than player 2 and 3. Hence the  $\mathrm{P}(X < Y < Z)$. Since its all geometric and independent this is indeed an easy geometric series. But  $\mathrm{P}(X < Y < Z) + \mathrm{P}(X < Z < Y)$ should be the answer right? Or do I need to add something else to this?

Comment: If your situation is as you describe, then no. $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$ are not much help to you at all, as they only describe the *first* time that a players get a head but a player might only win on e.g. their third head (if their first two heads were in drawn rounds). You might define some new variables (let's say $U$, $V$, $W$) as the first time that a player gets a *winning head* (i.e. they get a head but their opponents don't), but then note that $U$, $V$ and $W$ are no longer independent since if $U=1$ then $P(V=1)=0$ (player 2 can't have a winning head in round 1 if player 1 did).

Comment: @Silverfish ah yeah I get it! This isnt as nice as I hoped it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways to analyze this situation, but the following one is appealing for its simplicity and use of only the most basic properties of probability.  Assuming ties for heads cause the game to continue until a result is uniquely determined, it shows the chance of a player winning the game is her *relative odds*: the proportion of her odds of heads, divided by the sum of the odds of heads among all players. The game length obviously has a geometric distribution. Its parameter is proportional to this sum of odds. The constant of proportionality is the product of all the chances of tails.

Other methods of resolving ties (to create a definite winner) can be analyzed in a similar way, starting with computing the chance that a given player will win a particular round and continuing as shown here.

---

Let there be $m$ players, each using a coin with probability $p_i$ of heads.  Let $i,j,\ldots, k$ be any permutation of $(1,2,\ldots,m)$.

Suppose that when a tie occurs, no outcome is declared and play continues.  Then the chance that player $i$ wins is the chance that she is the sole person to toss heads, equal to

$$p_i(1-p_j)\ldots(1-p_k) = \frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\prod_{l=1}^m (1-p_l) = \pi_i Q$$

where I have written $\pi_i = p_i/(1-p_i)$ for player $i$'s odds of heads and $Q$ for the product of all $1-p_l$ (the chance that everybody simultaneously observes a tail).

If no player wins a round, the game starts over, with exactly the same probabilities.  Therefore the chance that player $i$ wins the entire game is the chance they can win a given round, divided by the sum of all players' chances to win the round:

$$\Pr(i\text{ wins}) = \frac{\pi_i Q}{\sum_{l=1}^m \pi_l Q} = \frac{\pi_i}{\sum_{l=1}^m \pi_l} = \frac{\pi_i}{\pi}.$$

It is their proportion of the total odds $\pi$.

The chance that the game ends on any particular round is the chance that exactly one player observes heads, equal to

$$\sum_{l=1}^m \pi_l Q = \pi Q.$$

Thus the length of the game has a geometric distribution with parameter $\pi Q$.

This result is supported by simulation:

[image: Figure]

It was carried out with this `R` script, which can simulate and summarize tens of millions of tosses per second for arbitrarily many players (up to limits determined by RAM).

```R
coins <- log(2:10); coins <- coins / sum(coins)
n.players <- length(coins)
n.rounds <- 1e6
#
# Simulate many rounds.
#
system.time({
  tosses <- matrix(runif(n.rounds * n.players), nrow=n.players) < coins
  wins <- colSums(tosses) == 1
  winners <- colSums(1:n.players * tosses) * wins
  (results <- tabulate(winners[winners != 0], n.players))
})
#
# Compare to theory.
#
odds <- coins / (1-coins)
p <- odds / sum(odds)
rbind(Simulation=results / sum(results), Theory=p)
#
# Display the distribution of game lengths compared to the geometric distribution.
#
lengths <- diff(c(0, which(wins==TRUE)))
Q <- prod(1 - coins)
pQ <- sum(odds) * Q
n.max <- ceiling((log(.002) + log(pQ)) / log(1-pQ)) # Plotting limit
prob.geometric <- (1 - pQ)^(1:n.max - 1) * pQ

subtitle <- paste(sum(results),"games played with coins", 
                  paste(round(coins, 2), collapse=","))
hist(lengths[lengths < n.max], freq=FALSE, breaks=(1:n.max)-1/2,
     main="Simulation (bars) vs. Theory (lines)",
     xlab="Game lengths",
     sub=subtitle)

invisible(sapply(1:n.max, function(i) {
  lines(c(i,i), c(0, prob.geometric[i]), lwd=2, col="Red")
}))
```